# The value obtained by Async Clipboard API is different from the value obtained from PasteEvent

Tags: javascript, excel, clipboard, paste

The content obtained by using the Async Clipboard API and the content obtained by pasting the data copied from Excel with Ctrl + V are different.

Below is the code using the AsyncClipboard API,

```
//
// Triggered from any events other than "paste"
//
const readData = await navigator.clipboard.read();
for (const one of readData) {
  if (one.types.includes('text/html')) {
    const blobHtml = await one.getType('text/html')
    const html = await blobHtml.text();

    console.log(html);
  }
}
//// old code
//const html = await navigator.clipboard.read().then(async (data) => {
//  for (const one of data) {
//    if (one.types.includes('text/html')) {
//      const blobHtml = await one.getType('text/html')
//      return await blobHtml.text();
//    }
//  }
//  return null;
//});
//
//console.log(html);
```

And here is the code for the paste event,

```
document.getElementById('xxx').addEventListener('paste', (event) => {
  console.log(event.clipboardData.getData('text/html'));
});
```

The first result is this...

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="80" style="border-collapse:
 collapse;width:60pt">
 <colgroup><col width="80" style="width:60pt">
 </colgroup><tbody><tr height="25" style="height:18.75pt">
  <td height="25" class="xl66" width="80" style="height:18.75pt;width:60pt">XXXX</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height="25" style="height:18.75pt">
  <td height="25" class="xl67" style="height:18.75pt">XXXXXXXX</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height="25" style="height:18.75pt">
  <td height="25" class="xl67" style="height:18.75pt">XXXX</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height="25" style="height:18.75pt">
  <td height="25" class="xl67" style="height:18.75pt">XXXX</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height="25" style="height:18.75pt">
  <td height="25" class="xl68" style="height:18.75pt">XXXX<br>
    </td>
 </tr>
 <tr height="25" style="height:18.75pt">
  <td height="25" class="xl68" style="height:18.75pt">XXXX<br>
    </td>
 </tr>
 <tr height="25" style="height:18.75pt">
  <td height="25" class="xl68" style="height:18.75pt">XXXX</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height="25" style="height:18.75pt">
  <td height="25" class="xl68" style="height:18.75pt">XXXX</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height="25" style="height:18.75pt">
  <td height="25" class="xl67" style="height:18.75pt">XXXX</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height="25" style="height:18.75pt">
  <td height="25" class="xl67" style="height:18.75pt">XXXX</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height="25" style="height:18.75pt">
  <td height="25" class="xl69" style="height:18.75pt">XXXX</td>
 </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

The next result is this

```
<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">

<head>
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name=ProgId content=Excel.Sheet>
<meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Excel 15">
<link id=Main-File rel=Main-File
href="file:///C:/Users/XXX/AppData/Local/Temp/msohtmlclip1/01/clip.htm">
<link rel=File-List
href="file:///C:/Users/XXX/AppData/Local/Temp/msohtmlclip1/01/clip_filelist.xml">
<style>
<!--table
    {mso-displayed-decimal-separator:"\.";
    mso-displayed-thousand-separator:"\,";}
@page
    {margin:.75in .7in .75in .7in;
    mso-header-margin:.3in;
    mso-footer-margin:.3in;}
.font5
    {color:windowtext;
    font-size:6.0pt;
    font-weight:400;
    font-style:normal;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:"Meiryo UI", monospace;
    mso-font-charset:128;}
tr
    {mso-height-source:auto;
    mso-ruby-visibility:none;}
col
    {mso-width-source:auto;
    mso-ruby-visibility:none;}
br
    {mso-data-placement:same-cell;}
td
    {padding-top:1px;
    padding-right:1px;
    padding-left:1px;
    mso-ignore:padding;
    color:black;
    font-size:11.0pt;
    font-weight:400;
    font-style:normal;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:メイリオ, monospace;
    mso-font-charset:128;
    mso-number-format:General;
    text-align:general;
    vertical-align:middle;
    border:none;
    mso-background-source:auto;
    mso-pattern:auto;
    mso-protection:locked visible;
    white-space:nowrap;
    mso-rotate:0;}
.xl66
    {color:windowtext;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-weight:700;
    font-family:"Meiryo UI", monospace;
    mso-font-charset:128;
    text-align:left;
    border-top:.5pt solid windowtext;
    border-right:none;
    border-bottom:.5pt solid windowtext;
    border-left:.5pt solid windowtext;
    background:#D9E1F2;
    mso-pattern:black none;}
.xl67
    {color:#444444;
    font-family:"Meiryo UI", monospace;
    mso-font-charset:128;
    text-align:left;
    border-top:none;
    border-right:none;
    border-bottom:none;
    border-left:.5pt solid windowtext;}
.xl68
    {font-family:"Meiryo UI", monospace;
    mso-font-charset:128;
    border-top:none;
    border-right:none;
    border-bottom:none;
    border-left:.5pt solid windowtext;}
.xl69
    {color:#444444;
    font-family:"Meiryo UI", monospace;
    mso-font-charset:128;
    text-align:left;
    border-top:none;
    border-right:none;
    border-bottom:.5pt solid windowtext;
    border-left:.5pt solid windowtext;}
ruby
    {ruby-align:left;}
rt
    {color:windowtext;
    font-size:6.0pt;
    font-weight:400;
    font-style:normal;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:メイリオ, monospace;
    mso-font-charset:128;
    mso-char-type:katakana;
    display:none;}
-->
</style>
</head>

<body link="#0563C1" vlink="#954F72">

<table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width=80 style='border-collapse:
 collapse;width:60pt'>
<!--StartFragment-->
 <col width=80 style='width:60pt'>
 <tr height=25 style='height:18.75pt'>
  <td height=25 class=xl66 width=80 style='height:18.75pt;width:60pt'>XXXX</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=25 style='height:18.75pt'>
  <td height=25 class=xl67 style='height:18.75pt'>XXXX</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=25 style='height:18.75pt'>
  <td height=25 class=xl67 style='height:18.75pt'>XXXX</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=25 style='height:18.75pt'>
  <td height=25 class=xl67 style='height:18.75pt'>XXXX</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=25 style='height:18.75pt'>
  <td height=25 class=xl68 style='height:18.75pt'>XXXX<br>
    </td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=25 style='height:18.75pt'>
  <td height=25 class=xl68 style='height:18.75pt'>XXXX<br>
    </td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=25 style='height:18.75pt'>
  <td height=25 class=xl68 style='height:18.75pt'>XXXX</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=25 style='height:18.75pt'>
  <td height=25 class=xl68 style='height:18.75pt'>XXXX</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=25 style='height:18.75pt'>
  <td height=25 class=xl67 style='height:18.75pt'>XXXX</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=25 style='height:18.75pt'>
  <td height=25 class=xl67 style='height:18.75pt'>XXXX</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=25 style='height:18.75pt'>
  <td height=25 class=xl69 style='height:18.75pt'>XXXX</td>
 </tr>
<!--EndFragment-->
</table>

</body>

</html>
```

As you can see, the programmatically acquired one lacks style information.
Is there a way to get style information like PasteEvent in AsyncClipboard API?

Comment: Yeah you are mixing the "traditional" `.then` and the more modern `async/await` syntaxes, that's often hard to come up with something clean this way. Use one or the other.

Comment: sorry, I didn't notice,,  It is the result of combining codes that I have investigated from various webpage.